# how do i analyze the stored procedures and identify why the data in the tables not getting updated?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The stored procedure "sp_ManagersToUpdate" updates the new managers against     the employees after a scheduled task named AutoUser is executed daily.
 but the problem is ..it has been identified since a month that some users managers are not getting updated as .. its showing the old managers against it..
I am pasting the code in "sp_ManagersToUpdate" stored procedure.
i need to analyze why those users's managers are not getting updated.

```
select emp.EmployeeID,
emp.FirstName,
emp.LastName,
case
       when ((rtrim(isnull(emps.exchange_id,'')) =       rtrim(isnull(ex.manager,''))) and (rtrim(isnull(emps.exchange_id,'')) =   rtrim(isnull(ad.manager,''))))  then 'Same'
    else ''
end
as Same,
isnull(emps.exchange_id,'') as Employee_Manager,
isnull(ex.manager,'') as Exchange_Manager,
isnull(ad.manager,'') as AD_Manager,
ad.samaccountname as Logon,
ex.Email

from tb_employee emp
inner join tb_exchange ex
on emp.exchange_id = ex.adspath
inner join tb_ad ad
on emp.username = ad.samaccountname
inner join tb_employee_lawson l
on emp.employeeid = l.emp_empnum
inner join tb_supervisors s
on l.emp_supervisor = s.supervisorid
inner join tb_employee emps
on s.employeeid = emps.employeeid

where (emp.username > '')
and
((rtrim(isnull(emps.exchange_id,'')) <> rtrim(isnull(ex.manager,''))) 
    or (rtrim(isnull(emps.exchange_id,'')) <> rtrim(isnull(ad.manager,'')))
    or (@ShowAllManagers = 1))

order by emp.employeeid
```

Comment: For a start, the column 'Same' is always going to have entry '' (unless you put @showallmanagers = 1) because the where clause says that either emps.exchange_id <> ex.manager or emps.exchange_id <> ad.manager, and then the select case when looks for emps.exchange_id to be equal to both. So that column seems pretty pointless. Other than it's too hard to guess what you're asking.

Comment: yes ... the stored procedure has the @showallmanagers = 0 in teh codebase.. sorry i didnot include it in the codebase..

Comment: Please help with the above issue

Comment: Sorry - I'd have to physically be there to help any further. There's just way too much info missing from your question. Maybe someone else can see something I can't.